# PostgreSQL delete fails with ON DELETE rule on inherited table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, rules

In my PostgreSQL 9.1 database I've defined RULEs that delete rows from child tables whenever a parent table row is deleted. This all worked OK, until I introduced inheritance. If the parent (referencing) table `INHERITS` from another table and I delete from the base table then the DELETE succeeds, but the RULE doesn't appear to fire at all - the referenced row is not deleted. If I try to delete from the derived table I get an error:

```
update or delete on table "referenced" violates foreign key constraint "fk_derived_referenced" on table "derived"
```

There is no other row in the parent table that would violate the foreign key: it's being referenced by the row that's being deleted! How do I fix this?

The following script reproduces the problem:

```
-- Schema

CREATE TABLE base
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT pk_base PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE referenced
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  value character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT pk_referenced PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE derived
(
  referenced_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_derived PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_derived_referenced FOREIGN KEY (referenced_id) REFERENCES referenced (id)
)
INHERITS (base);

-- The rule

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE rl_derived_delete_referenced
AS ON DELETE TO derived DO ALSO
DELETE FROM referenced r WHERE r.id = old.referenced_id;

-- Some test data

INSERT INTO referenced (id, value)
VALUES (1, 'referenced 1');

INSERT INTO derived (id, name, referenced_id)
VALUES (2, 'derived 2', 1);

-- Delete from base - deletes the "base" and "derived" rows, but not "referenced"
--DELETE FROM base
--WHERE id = 2;

-- Delete from derived - fails with:
-- update or delete on table "referenced" violates foreign key constraint "fk_derived_referenced" on table "derived"
DELETE FROM derived
WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: The straightforward way to do this would be to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the foreign key reference, and delete from the table "referenced" instead of from "derived". (And that works, too.)  Is there a compelling reason you chose not to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this seems an unusual way to do things. But you can make it work with a deferred constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE derived
(
  referenced_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_derived PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_derived_referenced FOREIGN KEY (referenced_id) 
    REFERENCES referenced (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
INHERITS (base);
```

The PostgreSQL docs, [Rules vs. Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-triggers.html), say

> Many things that can be done using triggers can also be implemented
>   using the PostgreSQL rule system. One of the things that cannot be
>   implemented by rules are some kinds of constraints, especially foreign
>   keys.

But it's not clear to me that this specific limitation is what you're running into.

Comment: Virtual +1 for @Catcall. I cannot vote, because I'm not registered.

Comment: Thanks, DEFERRED does work around the problem. I ended up using a TRIGGER instead of a RULE in the end, which has no such problem.

Comment: Congratulations on hitting 10K, by the way!

Comment: @EMP: Thanks. 10K in 8 months--at this pace I expect to catch Jon Skeet in 2038. Of course, by then he will have moved ahead 40 years or so.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to check if **other** records are still referencing the to-be-deleted rows. I added a test derived record#3, which points to the same #1 reference record.

```
-- The rule    
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE rl_derived_delete_referenced
AS ON DELETE TO tmp.derived DO ALSO (
    DELETE FROM tmp.referenced re_del
    WHERE re_del.id = OLD.referenced_id
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tmp.derived other
        WHERE other.referenced_id = re_del.id
        AND other.id <> OLD.id )
        ;
    );

-- Some test data

INSERT INTO tmp.referenced (id, value)
VALUES (1, 'referenced 1');

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
INSERT INTO tmp.derived (id, name, referenced_id)
VALUES (2, 'derived 2', 1); 

INSERT INTO tmp.derived (id, name, referenced_id)
VALUES (3, 'derived 3', 1);

-- Delete from base - deletes the "base" and "derived" rows, but not "referenced"
--DELETE FROM base
--WHERE id = 2;

-- Delete from derived - fails with:
-- update or delete on table "referenced" violates foreign key constraint "fk_derived_referenced" on table "derived"

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
DELETE FROM tmp.derived
WHERE id = 2
    ;

SELECT * FROM tmp.base;
SELECT * FROM tmp.derived;
SELECT * FROM tmp.referenced;
```